# Many To Many Polymorphic Relations Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism, laravel-5.4

I'd like to establish a many to many polymorphic relation in Laravel. (I'm new to it)

A user can have many profile types
Profile types are like Admin, Webmaster, ProjectManager.
I created a polymorphic relation and a pivot table for the profiles.

```
class User {

    public function profiles(){
        return Profile::where('user_id', $this->id);
    }

}

class Webmaster { // and class Admin, Projectmanager

   public function profiled(){
       return $this->morphToMany(Profile::class, 'profileable');
   }

   public function saveToUser($user)
   {
       $profile = new Profile;
       $profile->user_id = $user->id;
       return $this->profiled()->save($profile);
   }

}
```

Now I can save the models to the corresponding User.

```
$projectManager->saveToUser($user);
$webmaster->saveToUser($user);
```

It gets all saved to the pivot table as expected and the relations are valid.

profiles table looks like this:

```
id
user_id
profilable_id
profilable_type
```

Now the problem is retrieving a model collection of my profiles. I get the Profile types, but I dont get the Webmaster and ProjectManager.

So the question is: how do I get this model collection in this example?

Comment: It's better to say Many To Many Polymorphic Relation.

Comment: @MortezaRajabi Thanks, I made the edit. Can you help me out on the awnser?

Comment: Yes, I'm going to answer your question with little changes in your in you naming to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Your model structure is going to be like:

```
class Webmaster extends Model
{        
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Profile', 'userable');
    }
}

class Admin extends Model
{        
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Profile', 'userable');
    }
}

// and ProjectManager, ....
```

User Model:

```
class User extends Model
{        
    public function webmasters()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Webmaster', 'userable');
    }

    public function admins()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Admin', 'userable');
    }
}
```

Database schema:

```
webmasters
    id - integer
    ...

admins
    id - integer
    ...

users
    id - integer
    ...

userables
    user_id - integer
    userable_id - integer
    userable_type - string
```

Now, you can retrieve the relations:

```
$webmaster = App\Webmaster::find(1);

// retrieve users of a profile
foreach ($webmaster->users as $user) {
    //
}

$user = App\User::find(1);

// retrieve webmaster profiles of a user
foreach ($user->webmasters as $webmasters) {
    //
}
```

Actually, your profiles (webmaster, admin, projectmanager) are userable.

Comment: Thank you for your awnser! It is very helpful. 
I might not have been clear on what I wanted to achieve. 
A User can have a collection of one Webmaster and/or one Admin
So I can do something like: $user->profiles() // Retrieves [Webmaster, Admin]

Comment: Ok, I got what you need. I'm going to edit my answer.

Comment: It seems that there is no way to do that. Because they may have different table structures, and making query through those tables with one query is something impractical. It is better to set one relation for each of them or use the above answer.

Comment: Okay, bit of a bummer. Could you explain why the table structure is relevent, they only need an ID? Right now i have the relations in the profile table (id change it as you suggested) 
Where user1 has a link to a projectmanager id and webmaster id.

Comment: I only need a way to convert the profile collection to the corresponding models. (If there is a laravel way to do this)

What would you suggest to do otherwise?

Comment: You need to have all those attributes from admins table or webmaster table and the may have different structures. So one query($user->profiles()) can not get different data from different tables.

Comment: If your profiles share the same data structure, keep them in a table and distinguish them with separate column in the table(for example: profile_name)